# Can't SSH into server through Node (programmatically) using child process spawn

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, encoding, child-process

I am trying to get a simple bash script running in node.js so I can read and write out of it and I'm having difficulties. Here is a simple route I have in node.js:

```
router.post('/initiateSSH', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('inside /initiateSSH')
    var shellpath = path.join(__dirname, 'SSH.sh')

    const runCmd = (cmd) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
        var child = spawn(shellpath)
        var resp = ''
        child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { resp += buffer.toString() })
        child.stderr.on('data', function(data){console.log('error: ', data.toString())})
        child.stdout.on('close', function () { resolve(resp) })
      })
    }

    runCmd().then(ret => console.log(ret))
}
```

And the script I call:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p rocks ssh -tt jorgrun@crawl.jorgrun.rocks
```

So if you go to that address in the terminal it will be a log in for a roguelike game. If you try and programmatically call that bash file, it will display nothing (no error either). I've made sure that the bash file is executable (SSH.sh).

Not sure what it could be - this seems like the right way to do it from everything I've read online. I've even got the -tt flag for interactive scripting.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

---

**NOTES**

---

- Someone mentioned that this may be because the game loads a graphical interface using something called curses or ncurses. If that's the case I would want to grab the data and convert it into text.

Comment: Couple points **1** What does you script do if you start it outside of node.js?  Does that work?  **2** Can you ssh manually into `crawl.jorgrun.rocks` with your `jorgrun` user?  **3** The script you showed here does nothing more than login on server `crawl.jorgun.rocks`.  It does nothing else.  What are you expecting to happen?  I feel like it is missing something - like some command(s) to run.  With just that, it is normal you get nothing back. **4** If you have ssh issues, run it with `-v -v -v` arguments for full logs.  **5** Put `#!/bin/bash -x` in your script for more logs.